# The VPS in my Windows Server 2008 can not access the Internet

Tags: networking, vps

In my Windows Server's Hyper-V I created a CentOS 6.9 VPS.

[image]

and in its settings, its network interface adapter is using `Local Connectivity 2 - Virtual Network`.

this is the detail of the virtual network.

[image]

I configured a IP address(43.1.1.2) in the VPS(CentOS 6.9), and the Windows Server's IP address is (43.1.1.1), the network between them are interflow each other. because I can ping each other, but I can not in my Local network to access the VPS's IP address(`43.1.1.2`). and I also can not access the Internet in the VPS.

Comment: You’ve got the VM attached to the external network interface. If you want to communicate with the rest of the world then the VM has to have an IP configuration compatible with the rest of your LAN. That would typically mean the VM has a DHCP provided address or a an IP address similar to 192.168.1.x or 10.x.x.x. But, 43.1.1.2 is not an IP address scheme that should be found on any LAN.

Comment: @Appleoddity Do you mean I should add a more virtual interface (its IP is `192.168.*` like ) on the VPS?

Comment: I’m saying treat the VM the same as if it was a physical machine that you literally plugged in to your existing network. The IP address configuration it uses should be similar to all other machines on your network. The VM is not using the hyper-v server to communicate on the LAN and I doubt 43.1.1.x is what your LAN is actually using.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you, brother, you helped me. I found my Gateway configuration is wrong.